# SQL where condition with from and until

Tags: mysql

How would I combine the below:

```
        IF( IF(news_publish_until IS NOT NULL,
               news_publish_until, NOW())
        >= NOW(),1,0)

        IF( IF(news_publish_until IS NOT NULL,
               news_publish_until, NOW())
        <= NOW(),1,0)
```

The SQL must return 1 if the condition is TURE, IE falls within the Publish from/until date. Also if the date is empty NULL is set instead of 0000-00....

This is where I have got to so far:

```
    IF(news_publish_from >= NOW() AND (news_publish_until >= NOW() OR news_publish_until IS NULL), 1,
         IF(news_publish_from >= NOW() AND (news_publish_until &lt;= NOW() OR news_publish_from IS NULL), 1, 0))
```

Comment: What is this? Looks like VB code marked up in an XML document?

Comment: Its for our Zend CMS built around XML config. Everything in the <sql> parts acts like normal SQL.

Comment: You're going to need to find the correct tag for this question.  This isn't SQL.  Your CMS may be converting it to SQL in some fashion, but just when the CMS says <sql>, it lies.

Comment: But the database type can be changed so calling it <mysql> would be a lot worse.

Comment: This isn't direct input into ANY relational database.  I assume it's input into the CMS's engine that rewrites it into the correct SQL for that database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I get the idea. You think you're looking for something like this:

```
select *,
  (news_publish_from <= now() or news_publish_from is null) and
  (news_publish_until >= now() or news_publish_until is null)
  as result
from supportContacts
```

So, I think you should put this in your `sql` tag:

```
news_publish_from <= now() or news_publish_from is null) and
(news_publish_until >= now() or news_publish_until is null)
```

You can play with it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3eff7/1). Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks although like in the examples I need this in an IF() so that it return 1 if it is true. ALso not sure if it makes a difference but this SQL code is parsed into the WHERE part

Comment: The result is either 1 or 0. See the example. I don't understand what you said about the WHERE part.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what you said. If you wanted it filtered in the where clause add it to that clause. The example shows you the result visually, if I add a where clause then you wouldn't see what it's filtering, right? Anyway, it will work both ways in the WHERE and SELECT clause, regardless of what that weird <sql> tag is doing there